# Facebook authentication procedure

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have started learning about Facebook apps a few days ago. I created a very simple app with few lines of html code. Can any one tell me how to authenticate users or help me locate resources on the web that teaches me how to do this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/login/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nikhil. Where / What have you tried so far? I'm sure for a procedure like this, a simple Google search will throw up a lot of resources.

Comment: Thank you. I created an app. Trying to learn how to pull user's information and authenticate user to use my app Using this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-canvas/#prereqs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making the facebook apps, start from here: [Apps on facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/). Or, if you have created the app and configured the settings successfully, jump directly to here: [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth)

Also, download the [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/web/#sdks), they have some examples that will help you understanding the basics.